# Conditionally override link path

Tags: 7, theming

Have the following code

```
    $links = array_merge($links, array(
      l(t('Administration pages'), 'admin'),
      l(t('Front page'), '<front>'),
     ));
    }

    $output = theme('item_list', array('items' => $links, 'title' => t('Next steps')));
```

It does `<ul>` html list. My goal is to override, for example, "admin" path on given page from my custom module. Since it's themed output, I can use `hook_theme_registry_alter()` to override the theme function. But seems I can't do that dynamically (because of cache).

Is it wise solution to copy whole `theme_item_list` function, rename it to `my_theme_item_list` and write there my own path logic?

Another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do anything you could do in my_theme_item_list in a preprocess function. You can do this in your template.php file with a function like:

```
function mythemename_preprocess_item_list(&$vars) {
  // Change things here
}
```